# Grid slices the content

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to work a little with the css grids. Until now I have managed to stack these contents on top of each other, and when the screen gets smaller, I want to display them in 2 rows with 2 columns each.

The problem is that when doing so, the grid is slicing up the content? How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is the code I used:

```
    #top-story {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(450px, 1fr));
        column-count: 4;
    }
    #top-story .top-news {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 4;
    }
    #top-story .news-rows {
        grid-row-start: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="top-story">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="top-news">
                        <img src="images/test.jpg" />
                        <div id="gradient">
                            <div id="headline">
                                <div id="category">
                                    Galleri
                                </div>

                                Forårstopscorer Jung: Fortjener ikke at blive sammenlignet med Kamil – endnu
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="news-rows">
                    Nyheder
                    <div style="width: 100%; height: 10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div id="story">
                            <img src="images/test.jpg" />

                            <div id="seperator">&nbsp;</div>

                            <div id="info">
                                <div id="inside-content">
                                    <div id="category">
                                        Galleri
                                    </div>

                                    Forårstopscorer Jung: Fortjener ikke at blive sammenlignet med Kamil – endnu
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <br />

                    <a href="#">
                        <div id="story">
                            <img src="images/test.jpg" />

                            <div id="seperator">&nbsp;</div>

                            <div id="info">
                                <div id="inside-content">
                                    <div id="category">
                                        Galleri
                                    </div>

                                    Forårstopscorer Jung: Fortjener ikke at blive sammenlignet med Kamil – endnu
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <br />

                    <a href="#">
                        <div id="story">
                            <img src="images/test.jpg" />

                            <div id="seperator">&nbsp;</div>

                            <div id="info">
                                <div id="inside-content">
                                    <div id="category">
                                        Galleri
                                    </div>

                                    Forårstopscorer Jung: Fortjener ikke at blive sammenlignet med Kamil – endnu
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <br />

                    <a href="#">
                        <div id="story">
                            <img src="images/test.jpg" />

                            <div id="seperator">&nbsp;</div>

                            <div id="info">
                                <div id="inside-content">
                                    <div id="category">
                                        Galleri
                                    </div>

                                    Forårstopscorer Jung: Fortjener ikke at blive sammenlignet med Kamil – endnu
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

`top-news` is the large image and `news-rows` is the one with the four contents.

See image of the issue here:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `column-count`?

Comment: Because I want the second row to be divided into two columns of two rows, as the image shows. The issue is just that the second box is being sliced.

Comment: @MalthePedersen But you are already using grid for that, are you?

Comment: You can manage that layout without column-count...that's what CSS-Grid is for.

Comment: If I remove it, the four boxes just go on top of each other, full width in four rows? @Paulie_D

Comment: because you didn't make the element display:grid

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes I did, the #top-story is display:grid. The css code I have added is for when the browser is 1060px wide. So it is added.

Comment: *So it is added.* --> if we don't see it then it's *not* added. You are required to share your full relevant code

Comment: @TemaniAfif I thought it was obvious as I am talking about grids, sorry. It is added, yes. On full screen the large image is to the left, and the four boxes are on top of each other, to the right of the large image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to design for **Mobile** first, then **Desktop**. You will use CSS3 `@media` but `min-width` i.e.: `@media (min-width: 1024px){}`. Remove `column-count` from your code. You have to design infinity column. You have to transfer the column where you want using `grid-column-start` and `grid-row-start`. Also you should use a CSS prefixer for browser support. Use classes instead of ids.

Here is the snippet.

```css
.main-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1024px){
  .main-container{
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
.child-item{
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media (min-width: 1024px){
  .box-3{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
  }
  .box-4{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="child-item box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="child-item box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="child-item box-3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="child-item box-4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Explanation of the code:

First `.main-container` creates grid for **Mobile** view where use `grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr);`. No grid `column-count` property. Instead of `margin-bottom` I use `grid-row-gap: 30px;` for space between column in bottom. If browser window is more than or equal to `1024px`, `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* Create two column in side by side */` and use `grid-column-gap: 30px;` for separated from side by side column.

At this point in **Desktop** your box will be look like this.

[image]

Second, if you want to transfer `box-3` where is `box-2` in **Desktop** view in `@media` `box-3` will be `grid-column-start: 2;`, `grid-row-start: 1;` and `box-4` `grid-column-start: 2;`, `grid-row-start: 2;`. **Box 4** will be auto resize when you set `column 3` specific CSS.

Now **Desktop** view change like this.

[image]

Please read about [CSS Grid here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Please avoid using random syntax highlighting for code and quotes for things that aren't code or quotes. They have specific meanings, and, when used inappropriately, can make it difficult to impossible to understand the content.